# Add orders transaction id to admin new order email notification in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, email-notifications

I am trying to find a way to add the Authorize.net ID (not the woocommerce customer ID) to the admin order template. The Authorize.net ID shows on the order screen:

[image: See screenshot of order screen.]

I want that ID # to go in the email. Here is the e-mail template:

```
<?php
/**
 * Admin new order email
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates/Emails/HTML
 * @version 2.5.0
 */

 if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
 }

 /**
  * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
  */
 do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

 <p><?php printf( __( 'You have received an order from %s. The order is as follows:', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_billing_full_name() ); ?></p>


 <?php

 /**
  * @hooked WC_Emails::order_details() Shows the order details table.
  * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_order_data() Generates structured data.
  * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::output_structured_data() Outputs structured data.
  * @since 2.5.0
  */

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

 /**
  * @hooked WC_Emails::order_meta() Shows order meta data.
  */
 do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email, $transaction_ID );

 /**
  * @hooked WC_Emails::customer_details() Shows customer details
  * @hooked WC_Emails::email_address() Shows email address
  */
 do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );



 /**
  * @hooked WC_Emails::email_footer() Output the email footer
  */
 do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

Any ideas? I appreciate any guidance I can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will display the transaction ID *(when it exists)* in Woocommerce admin email notifications:

```
// Display the payment gateway transwaction ID on email notifications
add_action('woocommerce_email_order_details', 'before_email_order_details_transaction_id', 5, 4 );
function before_email_order_details_transaction_id( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {

    if( $order->get_transaction_id() && $sent_to_admin )
        echo '<p><strong>' . __("Transaction id") . ': </strong>' . $order->get_transaction_id() . '<p>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Worked PERFECTLY. Thank you!